# Three.js touch events not working properly on mobile

Tags: reactjs, three.js

So I have an interactive 3D globe, built with three.js and a mock database.

When you click on a country, it makes a call to the mock database and returns the information in a pop up. It works perfectly on desktop but I'm having continual issues with mobile.

By adding in touch events I've now been able to get the country when touching on mobile, however it doesn't seem to be making the call to the database using the UsersManager function.

I appreciate this is a bit lengthy but I also can't pop it onto a codesandbox as it's currently around 50 files.

If anyone can spot anything that I need to do in the 'test' function, I'd be grateful.

[Desktop PopUp Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu7J1.png)

```
import { PerspectiveCamera, Raycaster, WebGLRenderer } from "three";

import CountriesManager from "./CountriesManager";
import HitDetector from "./HitDetector";
import Loader from "./loader";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import SceneDetection from "./scenes/SceneDetection";
import SceneMain from "./scenes/SceneMain";
import UsersManager from "./UsersManager";
import { getMouse } from "./utils";
import { onCountryClick } from "./AppSignals";

export default class SceneApp {
  init() {
    this.loadAssets(); // FIRST THING -> load assets
  }

  loadAssets() {
    const loader = new Loader();

    loader.load(
      ["assets/earthtemplate.jpg", "assets/circle.png", "assets/worldmap.gif"],
      this.onLoadingComplete
    );
  }

  // only initialise scene when the assets are all loaded
  onLoadingComplete = () => {
    this.countryText = document.getElementById("countryName");
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.countryText = document.getElementById("countryName");

    // lazy, to know which country we hovering we will update this html element
    // TODO: as we're using React, may be best to signal to the parent component to update its state.countryName ?

    UsersManager.init(); // ideally we won't have to do that when it's linked to a proper db
    CountriesManager.init(); // will link the countries colors to their name / id

    this.currentState = STATES.explore;
    this.easing = 0.2; // is camera animating around the globe?
    this.animating = false; // is camera animating around the globe?
    this._down = false; // is mouse down
    this._downAndMove = false; // is mouse down and moving at the same time?
    this._mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // could probably be in a class specific for Interaction
    this._target = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }; // the position for the camera to rotate around the globe
    this.scene = new SceneMain(); // main Scene with all the visual things in it
    this.scene.init();

    this.sceneDetection = new SceneDetection(); // this scene will only be used as a render texture to know which country we're hovering
    this.sceneDetection.init(); // it will only contain the colored globe

    const ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, ratio, 1, 3000);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 20, CAMERA_DIST);
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);

    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);

    this.controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.controls.enablePan = false;

    this.hitDetector = new HitDetector(
      this.sceneDetection,
      this.renderer,
      this.camera
    ); // hit detector will check what color we're hovering

    this.raycaster = new Raycaster();
    this.addEvents();
    this.update(); // starts the RAF loop
  };

  addEvents() {
    // resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize);
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onDown);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onUp);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMove);
    window.addEventListener("click", this.onClick);
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", this.test);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", this.onMove);
    window.addEventListener("touchend", this.onDown);

    this.resize();
  }

  removeEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize);
    window.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onDown);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onUp);
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMove);
    window.removeEventListener("click", this.onClick);
    window.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.test);
    window.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.test);
    window.removeEventListener("touchend", this.onDown);
  }

  test = e => {
    getMouse(e, this._mouse); // get the mouse position

    if (this.currentState !== STATES.explore) {
      // if we are focusing on a country, no white overlays on other countries
      if (this._down && this.currentState === STATES.select)
        this.currentState = STATES.animateOut; // if we're moving while having the mousepressing down, get out of the zoom

      return;
    }

    if (this._down) this._downAndMove = true; // we're moving while pressing down
    const color = this.hitDetector.update(this._mouse.x, this._mouse.y); // get the color from the hit detector
    const country = CountriesManager.getCountry(color); // get the country depending of the color

    if (country && country !== this.lastCountry) {
      // if that's a different country that we're hovering
      this.lastCountry = country;
      this.countryText.innerText = country.name;
      this.scene.onHoverCountry(country.id); // this will call a change of uniform in the shaders
      console.log(this.lastCountry);
    } else if (color === "ffffff".toUpperCase()) {
      this.lastCountry = null;

      this.scene.onHoverCountry(999999); // this will call a change of uniform in the shaders
    }

    console.log("this is working on mobile as a click", country);
  };

  onUp = e => {
    this._down = false;
    // if we were moving, means we're exploring so don't continue further more
    if (this._downAndMove) {
      this._downAndMove = false;

      return;
    }

    if (this.currentState === STATES.explore && this.lastCountry) {
      const int = this.getIntersection(this._mouse);
      if (int) {
        // zoom on the country
        const { x, y, z } = int.point;
        let scale =
          (GLOBE_RADIUS + (CAMERA_DIST - GLOBE_RADIUS) / 1.5) / GLOBE_RADIUS;

        this.animating = true;
        this._target.x = x * scale;
        this._target.y = y * scale;
        this._target.z = z * scale;
        this.currentState = STATES.animateIn; // see update function
      }

      // dispatch country / users
      const users = UsersManager.getUsersPerCountry(this.lastCountry.name);
      onCountryClick.dispatch(this.lastCountry.name, users);
    }
  };

  onDown = e => {
    this._down = true;
  };

  onMove = e => {
    getMouse(e, this._mouse); // get the mouse position

    // move particles up when moving the mouse on the sphere
    const int = this.getIntersection(this._mouse);
    if (int) this.scene.pushParticlesUp(int);

    if (this.currentState !== STATES.explore) {
      // if we are focusing on a country, no white overlays on other countries
      if (this._down && this.currentState === STATES.select)
        this.currentState = STATES.animateOut; // if we're moving while having the mousepressing down, get out of the zoom

      return;
    }

    if (this._down) this._downAndMove = true; // we're moving while pressing down
    const color = this.hitDetector.update(this._mouse.x, this._mouse.y); // get the color from the hit detector
    const country = CountriesManager.getCountry(color); // get the country depending of the color

    if (country && country !== this.lastCountry) {
      // if that's a different country that we're hovering
      this.lastCountry = country;
      this.countryText.innerText = country.name;
      this.scene.onHoverCountry(country.id); // this will call a change of uniform in the shaders
    } else if (color === "ffffff".toUpperCase()) {
      this.lastCountry = null;
      this.countryText.innerText = "";
      this.scene.onHoverCountry(999999); // this will call a change of uniform in the shaders
    }
  };

  getIntersection(pos) {
    const x = (pos.x / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1; // get the mouse coordinates between -1 and 1 (clipspace coordinates)
    const y = -(pos.y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    this.raycaster.setFromCamera({ x, y }, this.camera); // raycast
    let intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(
      this.sceneDetection.children
    ); // should only be one sphere
    return intersects[0]; // get first intersection
  }

  update() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    this.controls.update();

    // depending of the state of the globe (see consts file) we need to zoom in / out, etc.
    if (this.currentState === STATES.animateOut) {
      // in animate out of the selected view, need the camera to zoom back
      const dist = this.camera.position.length();
      const diff = CAMERA_DIST - dist;

      if (diff < 1) {
        // change the state if the camera is far enough
        this.currentState = STATES.explore;
      } else {
        const scale = CAMERA_DIST / dist;
        const newX = this.camera.position.x * scale;
        const newY = this.camera.position.y * scale;
        const newZ = this.camera.position.z * scale;

        this.camera.position.x += (newX - this.camera.position.x) * this.easing;
        this.camera.position.y += (newY - this.camera.position.y) * this.easing;
        this.camera.position.z += (newZ - this.camera.position.z) * this.easing;
      }
    } else if (this.currentState === STATES.animateIn) {
      // if animateIn, ease to the camera!
      // TODO to aboid jerkyness in the movement, you can clamp diffX, diffY, diffZ so it doesn't add too much in one frame
      const diffX = (this._target.x - this.camera.position.x) * this.easing;
      const diffY = (this._target.y - this.camera.position.y) * this.easing;
      const diffZ = (this._target.z - this.camera.position.z) * this.easing;
      this.camera.position.x += diffX;
      this.camera.position.y += diffY;
      this.camera.position.z += diffZ;

      // if we're close enough from the target, change state
      if (Math.abs(diffX * diffY * diffZ) < 0.01)
        this.currentState = STATES.select;
    } else if (this.currentState === STATES.explore && !this._down) {
      this.sceneDetection.update();
      this.scene.update();
    }

    this.raf = requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
  }

  resize = () => {
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  };

  unmount() {
    this.removeEvents();

    this.renderer.domElement.remove();
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.raf);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you isolated the underlying issue?  Can you step through your code with a debugger and see if the issue is that the service call is sending the wrong coordinates (probably the event position translation logic is incorrect)?  Right now it is difficult to help you with your code because your current example isn't a [mre].

Comment: You have your `touchend` event assigned to the same function as `mousedown`. (`window.addEventListener("touchend", this.onDown);`) Was this intentional? It seems they do (conceptually) different things. I would have expected `touchend` to align with `mouseup`, but I'm not entirely clear on your use-case.

Comment: @TheJim01 that's sorted it, thanks so much! I realise my example is not much to go on so really appreciate your input!

Comment: @zero298  I'd stepped through it and debugged but it was proving a bit elusive, thankfully it's now working with a tiny tweak as above. I'll try in future to make things mre but it's tricky with this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adding my comment as a full answer, so the question can be marked as solved.*

Your `touchend` event is currently pointing to the same handler as your `mousedown` event.

```js
window.addEventListener("touchend", this.onDown);
```

In most cases (though maybe not in yours), `touchend` equates to the `mouseup` event (which is where you have your database calls).

```js
window.addEventListener("touchend", this.onUp);
```

If this is correct, you should update your `removeEventListener`, too.